# Python: Converting a byte object to string, removing \'s, then writing to list brings back \'s. slashes

Tags: python, string, byte

I'm parsing html that's currently in byte form by converting it to a string then writing it to a list.
I want to remove all forward-slashes (or even just nicely handle escape characters).

Here's my code:

```
picture_divs = [b'<img alt="Python\'s Confusing me." class="" src="https://link_goes_here" style="whatever;"/>']

def get_alt_text(picture_divs):
    alt_text = []
    for i, elem in enumerate(picture_divs):
        str_elem = str(elem).replace('\\', '')  # Convert bytes -> strings
        start_index = int(str_elem.find('alt='))
        end_index = int(str_elem.find('class='))
        alt_text.append(str_elem[start_index + 4:end_index])

    return alt_text


alt_text_return = get_alt_text(picture_divs)
print(alt_text_return)
```

Output:
['"Python\'s Confusing me." ']

Desired output:
['"Python's Confusing me." ']

Comment: Your desired output is not possible. The string is delimited by `'` so these **must** be escaped otherwise they close the string. This is a syntax error: `'"Python's Confusing me." '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that you are asking for is an error for python syntax. Python creates list of the format

```
list_example = ['a','b']
```

If you wish to have 'Python's confusing' me in the list, then you see how the single quote opened is closed by your single quote. So python puts the backslash in order to override the single quote and not throw an error.

Comment: Aha! So what you're saying is alt_text[0] *is* formatted correctly, but the list needs the correct Python syntax to work. Is that accurate?

Comment: Yes, if you print your string out before returning it, then you can see that it is correctly formatted as you want it, just the append function will modify it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution to clean it up:

```
>>> from re import sub
>>> picture_divs = [b'<img alt="Python\'s Confusing me." class="" src="https://link_goes_here" style="wha
tever;"/>']
>>> for div in picture_divs:
...     rev1 = sub(r'[\\/]', '', div.decode('utf-8'))
...     rev2 = rev1.replace('\'', "'")
...     print(rev2)
... 
<img alt="Python's Confusing me." class="" src="https:link_goes_here" style="whatever;">
>>>
```